# Dynamodb pagination in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

How can pagination be done in dynamodb using ruby on rails, using aws-sdk in the following different occasions:

1. in a normal find result
2. in a search result